# Como abrir uma activity através de um botão

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-activity, intent

Estou tendo um problema para abrir minha activity em vário fórums e não achei a resposta.
Tenho a activity "TelaDeLogin" e a activity "Feed", e ja tentei abrir de várias formas, aqui está o código xml do button:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnEntrar"
        style="@style/BotaoComFundo"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/espacamento_Pequeno"
        android:text="@string/entrar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/editTextSenha"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        android:onClick="logar"/>
```

a seguir as formas que tentei programar o button pelo código java:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TelaDeLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_de_login);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnEntrar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                logar(v);
            }
        });
    }
    public void logar(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(TelaDeLogin.this, Feed.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Antes estava assim:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TelaDeLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_de_login);

         public void logar(View view){
        Intent i = new Intent(TelaDeLogin.this, Feed.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Tendo em vista os códigos, a `public class` do meu feed está declarado da seguinte maneira:

```
public class Feed extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
```

e eu percebi que todas as telas que tem o implement da `Navigation View` para a `Toolbar` e o `FeedDrawer` não consigo abrir através de um botão, então, como faço para conseguir abrir a class do `Feed` através do botão, pois sempre que clico no botão da um erro, porém na tela de perfil que não tinha o "implement" do NavigationView abria, e se colocar o "implement" `Navigation View` da erro e fecha o app também.

PS: a página do Feed abre normalmente se colocar para abrir ela primeiro, só não consigo acessá-la através do botão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem segredo, pode fazer dentro do `onClick` direto.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Feed.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: o app fecha no emulador e da esse erro : java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Comment: consegui arrumar, tinha colocado no action bar no xml mas não no theme do manifest, vlw <3